# Get <header><ul><li> in center of screen

Tags: html, css

still figuring a lot of things out and can use your help atm. I cant get my header list to be in the center of the page.

my HTML code:

```
  <header>
      <ul>
        <li><h5 class="button rightborder">Blog</h5></li>
        <li><h5 class="button">List Builder [WIP]</h5></li>
        <li><h5 class="button border title">CERBERUS</h5></li>
        <li><h5 class="button rightborder">Math Hammer</h5></li>
        <li><h5 class="button">Other</h5></li>
      </ul>
    </header>
```

And my CSS code:

```
body {
    background: black url("./background.jpg") no-repeat fixed center;
}

header {
    border-bottom: 1px double white;
    width: 100%;
    position: center;
}

h5 {
    color: white;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-size: 18px;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I hope you guys understand my question and are able to help.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Off topic: You seem to be using heading elements (H5) for styling. Please don't. https://webaim.org/techniques/semanticstructure/#correctly

Comment: thanks for this. Stil getting to learn stuff. This kind of stuff helps a lot. An example would be even better but as said like the help already!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the `text-align:center` should be on the ul instead of the li.

```css
body {
    background: black url("./background.jpg") no-repeat fixed center;
}

header {
    border-bottom: 1px double white;
    width: 100%;
    position: center;
}

h5 {
    color: white;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-size: 18px;
}
ul{    
  text-align: center;
  padding-left:0;

}
li {
    display: inline-block;

}
```

```html
  <header>
      <ul>
        <li><h5 class="button rightborder">Blog</h5></li>
        <li><h5 class="button">List Builder [WIP]</h5></li>
        <li><h5 class="button border title">CERBERUS</h5></li>
        <li><h5 class="button rightborder">Math Hammer</h5></li>
        <li><h5 class="button">Other</h5></li>
      </ul>
    </header>
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

set `ul {text-align: center}`

If you want nav to have full screen width set the following:

```
ul {display: table; width: 100%;}
li {display: table-cell;}
```

BTW: there's no `position: center`.

Comment: Will try this. Thank you for thinking along with me. Appreciate the help.